# How to get the correct obj in json?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json:

```
{  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{  
      "pages":{  
         "53309836":{  
            "pageid":53309836,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"March 4 Trump",
            "contentmodel":"wikitext",
            "pagelanguage":"en",
            "pagelanguagehtmlcode":"en",
            "pagelanguagedir":"ltr",
            "touched":"2018-06-12T21:00:59Z",
            "lastrevid":828824621,
            "length":12173,
            "fullurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_4_Trump",
            "editurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=March_4_Trump&action=edit",
            "canonicalurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_4_Trump"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which I get by running:

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids=<?php echo $pageId; ?>&inprop=url&format=json&callback=?", {
  format: "json"
 }, function(data) {
  $.each(data.query, function(i) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 });
});
```

I need `title`

I tried: `console.log(i.title);` and `console.log(i.pages.title);`

Comment: Well you would need something more along the lines of query.pages['53309836'].title

Comment: Actually it would be ```i.query.pages['53309836'].title``` if its in the variable ```i```, but yes @Enjayy is right.

Comment: @LukasBach (index):293 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '53309836' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `data.query.pages` then get the value using the index of title

   ```js
   var data = {  
      "batchcomplete":"",
      "query":{  
         "pages":{  
            "53309836":{  
               "pageid":53309836,
               "ns":0,
               "title":"March 4 Trump",
               "contentmodel":"wikitext",
               "pagelanguage":"en",
               "pagelanguagehtmlcode":"en",
               "pagelanguagedir":"ltr",
               "touched":"2018-06-12T21:00:59Z",
               "lastrevid":828824621,
               "length":12173,
               "fullurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_4_Trump",
               "editurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=March_4_Trump&action=edit",
               "canonicalurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_4_Trump"
            }
         }
      }
   }

     $.each(data.query.pages, function(index,value) {
       console.log(value.title);
    });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This would get you the title. The $.each function for an object returns the key value pair so you can use the key to get or the value. like so.

```
$.each(data.query.pages, function(key, value) {
 console.log(data.query.pages[key].title)
// or
 console.log(value.title)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close with your loop, but I would deserialize it and then iterate over all the pages to get the titles you want.

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids=<?php echo $pageId; ?>&inprop=url&format=json&callback=?", {
format: "json"
}, function(data) {
    var d = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.each(d.query.pages, function() {
        console.log(this.title);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you know the specific page you're looking for, you can use:

```
var d = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(d.query.pages['53309836'].title);
```

Hope that helps.